# Python Native Arbitrary Precision

Tags: python, arbitrary-precision

Is there any way of compiling Python's interpretter in such a way that it could use a native (c) arbitrary precision library so that Python could use arbitrary precision as if it was a normal number instead of having to use the decimal class?

EG.

```
>>0.00000001 + 1
1.00000001
```

Comment: Even if it is possible, you shouldn't do this. Code which depends on this to work correctly (or rather, accurately enough - decimals have limited precision as well) breaks when run on *any* other Python installation in the world. Code that doesn't just runs (a bit to quite a lot) slower while producing about the same results.

Comment: @delnan: Very well stated. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're unsatisfied with the builtin `decimal`, you can try several libraries that implement higher precision floating point numbers. Most of them, however, are not exactly "native" - you might clarify what you mean by that and why you need it.

1. [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) - it provides a pure-Python implementation of high-precision floating point numbers, but it can automatically switch to GNU MP if support for it is available on the system, it has an extensive set of features
2. [gmpy](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) - it provides a wrapper for the GNU MP library
3. [bigfloat](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bigfloat/) - it provides a wrapper for the GNU MPFR library (which is based on GNU MP; wrapper doesn't look very promising since it uses `ctypes`)
4. You can use Cython and use any of the above-mentioned libraries (e.g. GNU MP) directly, if it is required for a given performance-critical section. You can also make an ad-hoc Cython wrapper for your use case.

Comment: I am aware of the different options I have for arbitrary precision from libraries, however the problem is more about whether I can use them without as if they were normal Python floats, but precise.

Comment: You can't do that (without modifying Python itself); why do you want to do this, what do you expect to gain from it?

Comment: I am trying to find a way of using arbitrary precision without complicating the code more (an aim from management who don't really understand fp precision)

Comment: @jamesj: Management is not the issue.  Maintainability is the issue.  Explicit is better than implicit.